# The server SSL certificate failed to verify

Tags: git, ssl, github, github-for-mac

I push my code to github on Xcode7 Source Control, I get the error:

The server SSL certificate failed to verify. A secure connection to the server cannot be established as the server cannot be trusted

I use commond `git push` I receive the resonse ： `unable to access 'https://github.com/chengyanan/2015-08-06.git/': SSL: can't load CA certificate file /home/slvher/tools/https-ca/cacert.pem`

I use `curl http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem -o cacert.pem` to download cacert.pem. When I install cacert.pem I get error：An error occurred. Unable to import project. I cann't install cacert.pem.

Comment: Welcome to the Stack Exchange network!
As it stands, your question is unclear. You should edit it to add relevant details which could help someone answer it, e.g.,
the command you use to push to GitHub, the verbatim response you receive, the URL for your remote repository, etc. See the [How to Ask](http://serverfault.com/help/how-to-ask) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I use the SSH . Use commond `git remote set-url origin git@github.com:chengyanan/2015-08-06.git` to modify the address of the respository from `https://github.com/chengyanan/2015-08-06.git` to `git@github.com:chengyanan/2015-08-06.git`. Re-generate a new ssh and add to my github. Then it works!